# Querying /tags/tag-name/media/recent endpoint, how to avoid private photos

Tags: instagram

I'm currently hitting the /tags/tag-name/media/recent end point periodically and saving to my own database some media that match certain criteria. Sometimes, I get a private photo. This means that in my gallery, when I display said images, some of them show up as broken links, because the instagram image server replies 403 forbidden since those images are private.

How can I know which image is private to skip them?

I don't see from the end point response how I can do this.

Thanks!

Comment: I just realized I think I posted twice! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532999/instagram-api-how-to-know-a-medias-privacy-level But I think there might be 2 issues at hand here. One being privacy or NSFW flags, and the other being image URLs changing in time.

Comment: Another related stack post actually! (not mine though) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221352/retrieve-instagram-images-get-access-denied-message

Comment: Ok these are actually deleted photos, confirmed. I'll close my questions and rewrite a clearer question!

Answer (score 1):

Use `client_id` instead of `access_token` to make the `/tags/tag-name/media/recent` API call, then you should not get any private photos in response.

Comment: I'm currrently querying the end point through this url: https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/montreal/media/recent?client_id=[MyClientId]&min_tag_id=[LastMinTagId], so this is using client_id already.

Comment: which images are showing with broken links? http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/tags#montreal

Comment: Here are a few that I see from my list:
- http://distilleryimage9.s3.amazonaws.com/90f7fc0a943811e3908812d3c63eaff1_8.jpg
- http://distilleryimage7.s3.amazonaws.com/3a7e6c62943111e39f300e3607e3630b_7.jpg
- http://distilleryimage2.s3.amazonaws.com/da7f5202942d11e38e04127d69c3cd5e_8.jpg

I'm thinking that privacy might not be the problem, could it be some kind of "NSFW" rating? Thanks!

Comment: I've found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/instagram-api-developers/2_I-lManfOo

This mentions something interesting, currently, I save to my DB the complete raw JSON that instagram gave me. Then displaying my images I deserialize that. Maybe the picture file path / name has changed?